# How to properly point the Sun in CesiumJS?

Tags: cesium, altitude

I prepared a [Cesium sandcastle example](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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) based on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379147/convert-from-alt-az-coordinates-w-r-t-point-on-surface-to-x-y-z-w-r-t-earth-c/379173#379173) from @FSimardGIS, but something is going wrong: only one of many rays correctly points to the Sun, the other appears random.

[image: Screenshot]
What's wrong here?
I took the test coordinates from SunCalc library, but you can also insert data manually, using for example this site for calculations:

https://planetcalc.com/320/?day=2020-11-19%2004:31:37&plat=36.13&plon=138.36&gmtdiff=0&UTCoffset=0

This is the source code from the other answer:

```
function CalcPosFromAltAzDist(startPoint, vectorPointing) {
  var ellipsoid = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84;
  var ENU = new Cesium.Matrix4();
  Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(startPoint,ellipsoid,ENU);
  var myX = vectorPointing.dist * Math.sin(vectorPointing.az * Math.PI / 180);
  var myY = vectorPointing.dist * Math.cos(vectorPointing.az * Math.PI / 180);
  var myZ = vectorPointing.dist * Math.sin(vectorPointing.alt * Math.PI / 180);
  var offset = new Cesium.Cartesian3(myX,myY,myZ);
  var finalPoint = Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPoint(ENU, offset, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
  return finalPoint;    
}
```

Call with:

```
vectorPointing= {"alt" : 30, "az" : 0};
startPoint= Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(290.6, -35.78);
```

Comment: Oops, the cos(alt) factor in the myX and myY calculation is missing. I updated my answer to correct the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of malfunctioning of the algorith mentioned in the question were two wrong formulas; right function is:

```
function CalcPosFromAltAzDist(startPoint, vectorPointing) {

  var ellipsoid = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84;
  var ENU = new Cesium.Matrix4();
  Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(startPoint,ellipsoid,ENU);
  var myX = vectorPointing.dist * Math.cos(vectorPointing.alt * Math.PI / 180) * Math.sin(vectorPointing.az * Math.PI / 180);
  var myY = vectorPointing.dist * Math.cos(vectorPointing.alt * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(vectorPointing.az * Math.PI / 180);
  var myZ = vectorPointing.dist * Math.sin(vectorPointing.alt * Math.PI / 180);
  var offset = new Cesium.Cartesian3(myX,myY,myZ);
  var finalPoint = Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPoint(ENU, offset, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
  return finalPoint;
  
}
```

"Math.cos(vectorPointing.alt * Math.PI / 180)" factor was missing in myX and myY calculations.

Now all works fine:

[image: Screenshot of Cesium]

Look here for a working [sandcastle example](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

Answer (score 1):

I have built a solution based on different algorithm and Cesium functions.

I didn't understand anything about the transformations and methods used... :-)  , but it works fine.

[Sandcastle example.](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

Source code:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");
viewer.scene.globe.enableLighting = true;

var suntest = [];

suntest[0] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 0, 'lon' :-180, 'alt' : -69.936132980914, 'az' :170.491579546217};
suntest[1] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 0, 'lon' :-150, 'alt' : -51.732788127111, 'az' :123.115116564788};
suntest[2] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 0, 'lon' :-120, 'alt' : -24.870948550859, 'az' :111.897154212120};
suntest[3] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 0, 'lon' :-90, 'alt' : 3.248817322124, 'az' :109.809795550210};
suntest[4] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 0, 'lon' :-60, 'alt' : 31.247432115441, 'az' :113.313745536185};
suntest[5] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 0, 'lon' :-30, 'alt' : 57.331014803665, 'az' :128.816746856710};
suntest[6] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 0, 'lon' :0, 'alt' : 69.936132980893, 'az' :189.508420454115};
suntest[7] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 0, 'lon' :30, 'alt' : 51.732788127357, 'az' :236.884883435008};
suntest[8] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 0, 'lon' :60, 'alt' : 24.870948550745, 'az' :248.102845787901};
suntest[9] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 0, 'lon' :90, 'alt' : -3.248817321848, 'az' :250.190204449796};
suntest[10] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 0, 'lon' :120, 'alt' : -31.247432115554, 'az' :246.686254463785};
suntest[11] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 0, 'lon' :150, 'alt' : -57.331014803436, 'az' :231.183253143577};
suntest[12] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 0, 'lon' :180, 'alt' : -69.936132980873, 'az' :170.491579545552};
suntest[13] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 10, 'lon' :-180, 'alt' : -79.671227366220, 'az' :161.573903931188};
suntest[14] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 10, 'lon' :-150, 'alt' : -56.300357978857, 'az' :110.783422611356};
suntest[15] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 10, 'lon' :-120, 'alt' : -28.225368684317, 'az' :107.175147833478};
suntest[16] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 10, 'lon' :-90, 'alt' : -0.168643089275, 'az' :110.063187466725};
suntest[17] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 10, 'lon' :-60, 'alt' : 26.878473297456, 'az' :118.330636399825};
suntest[18] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 10, 'lon' :-30, 'alt' : 50.377210160732, 'az' :138.739128733690};
suntest[19] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 10, 'lon' :0, 'alt' : 60.029872737499, 'az' :186.514048228677};
suntest[20] = {'time' : '2020-11-20T12:00:00.000Z', 'lat' : 10, 'lon' :30, 'alt' : 45.598015050067, 'az' :227.849125941148};


function drawLine(x1,y1,z1, x2, y2, z2) {
  var origin = new Cesium.Cartesian3(x1,y1,z1);
  var dest = new Cesium.Cartesian3(x2,y2,z2);
 
  viewer.entities.add({
    polyline: {
        positions: [
          origin, 
          dest
          ],
      arcType: Cesium.ArcType.NONE   , 
      width: 20,
      material: new Cesium.PolylineArrowMaterialProperty(Cesium.Color.WHITE)
    }
  });  
}



function createROIfromRotation(position,  rotation, lengthKM) {
  // position: Cartographic - {latitude, longitude, altitude})
  // rotation: HeadingPitchRoll - {heading, pitch, roll}
  
  // Based on answer found here:
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58021985/create-a-point-in-a-direction-in-cesiumjs
  
    var cartesianPosition = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartographicToCartesian(position);

    rotation.heading = rotation.heading - Cesium.Math.toRadians(90);
    var referenceFrame1 = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(cartesianPosition, rotation);
    var rotationMatrix = Cesium.Matrix3.fromQuaternion(referenceFrame1, new Cesium.Matrix3());
    var rotationScaled = Cesium.Matrix3.multiplyByVector(rotationMatrix, new Cesium.Cartesian3(lengthKM * 1000.0, 0, 0), new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    var roiPos = Cesium.Cartesian3.add(cartesianPosition, rotationScaled, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    return roiPos;
}


function arrowFromTo(latitude, longitude, height, elev, azimut, lengthKM){
  latitude = Cesium.Math.toRadians(latitude);
  longitude = Cesium.Math.toRadians(longitude);
  var origin = new Cesium.Cartographic(longitude, latitude, height);
  var originC3 = new Cesium.Cartographic.toCartesian(origin);

  // Altitude (aka Elevation) and Azimuth can also be seen as Pitch and Heading, with Roll = 0:
  var heading = Cesium.Math.toRadians(azimut);
  var pitch = Cesium.Math.toRadians(elev);
  var roll = 0.0;
  var direction = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(heading, pitch, roll);
 
  
  ////////////
  var result = createROIfromRotation(origin, direction, lengthKM);
  ////////////
  
  drawLine(originC3.x ,originC3.y, originC3.z, result.x ,result.y, result.z);
}



// Bind button to test function:
document.getElementById("btnCalc").addEventListener("click",function(a,b,c) {
  var obsLat = document.getElementById("obsLat").value * 1.0;
  var obsLon = document.getElementById("obsLon").value * 1.0;
  var obsAlt = document.getElementById("obsAlt").value * 1.0;
  var sunAlt = document.getElementById("sunAlt").value * 1.0;
  var sunAz = document.getElementById("sunAz").value * 1.0;
  var userDate = document.getElementById("userDate").value;
  
  viewer.clock.currentTime = Cesium.JulianDate.fromDate(new Date(userDate));
  arrowFromTo(obsLat,obsLon,obsAlt,sunAlt,sunAz,150000000);
            //latitude, longitude, height, elev, azimut, lengthKM
});


///////////////////////
// Draw test lines:
  viewer.clock.currentTime = Cesium.JulianDate.fromDate(new Date(suntest[0].time));
  
  for (var i = 0; i<suntest.length; i++) {
    arrowFromTo(suntest[i].lat, suntest[i].lon, 0, suntest[i].alt, suntest[i].az,150000000 );
  }
```